# How to pause objective-c for an time less then an second

Tags: objective-c, floating-point, integer, sleep

I am writing an app in **Xcode 5.1.1** and **objective-c**.
I want to pause the program for 0.1 second. 
To pause an program I normally use something like this:

```
sleep(1);
```

But "sleep" only takes an integer.

**Question: is there an equivalent of sleep which can take floats?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use following code. Convert your time to micro seconds.

```
usleep(100000); //Sleep Time 0.1 seconds
usleep(1000000);//Sleep Time 1 second.
```

or

```
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1f];
```

Comment: Very old question but just came across this.. think you are missing a 0 in the 0.1 second. Have updated the answer.